# Unable to delete data from database

Tags: c#, linq

I encountered a problem whereby when the user clicked on the delete button, Nothing happens and when I insert breakpoint to check, The `selectLocStation` is null. Why is it happening? Can anyone kindly solve my doubts about it?

Here are the codes for you to see my Delete codes. Appreciate any helps that were offered.

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
    {
        int selectLocStation = Convert.ToInt32(cbLocStation.SelectedValue);

        var DeleteRTiming = 
            (from delLocStation in Setupctx.requiredtimings
             where delLocStation.RequiredLocationStationID == selectLocStation
             select delLocStation).SingleOrDefault();

        if (DeleteRTiming != null)
        {
            Setupctx.DeleteObject(DeleteRTiming);
            Setupctx.SaveChanges();
            cbLocStation.SelectedIndex = -1;
            this.Edit_TS_Load(null, EventArgs.Empty);
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Required Timing And " + 
                                "The Location Station Has Been Deleted.");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the codes that were used to bind.

```
private void Edit_TS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (satsEntities Setupctx = new satsEntities())
        {
            var DeleteRT = (from DelRT in Setupctx.requiredtimings
                            join locationstationname ls in Setupctx.locationstationnames on DelRT.RequiredLocationStationID equals ls.locationstationID
                                select ls.locStatname).Distinct().ToList();

            foreach (var locstationData in DeleteRT)
            {
                cbLocStation.Items.Add(locstationData);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, *is* there any data with that `RequiredLocationStationID` ?

Comment: what is the value for `cbLocStation.SelectedValue`?

Comment: You may be rebinding the "cbLocStation" before reaching the click event

Comment: how can `selectLocStation` be null ? it is of type int, are you getting any exception or you mean your object `DeleteRTiming` is null

Comment: The Values inside the cbLocStation initially were the primary keys of a viewdata, "locationstationname". I used foreign key to get the names and subsititute it so instead of showing the ids, I'm showing the names for the user to select.

Comment: as per your code it is not possible that value of selectLocStation is null. it must be either 0 or any integer value and if cbLocStation.SelectedValue is not convertable then you must get exception at that line. so tell exact problem.

Comment: @rookie The value of the select box should be the Id, and the Text should be the name

Comment: @manishparakhiya my bad. selectLocStation is stated as 0 and the var DeleteRTiming is null

Comment: @MoH The ids inside the combo box were represented by their names.

Comment: can you share the  code used for binding

Answer (score 1):

How can `selectLocStation` be null ? it is of type int, are you getting any exception or you mean your object DeleteRTiming is null ? probably its the `DeleteRTiming` which is null

The simple answer to that the record you are looking in the database against `selectLocStation` is not there.

You need to put a break point and see what is being held by 'selectLocStation` and then check the database manually if the record exists in the database.

Comment: OP said that selectLocStation is null.

Comment: @davenewza, how can it be null ? its being converted to int, it will raise an exception

Comment: That will never be null, he may have checked even before executing the line

Comment: @davenewza, its not the `selectLocStation` which is null , its `DeleteRTiming` which is null. OP has update the question

Answer (score 0):

when you bind your control, you must set it in ! IsPostback and persist you with ViewState

```
If(! IsPostBack)
{
  BindYourControl(); //For just first load.
}
```

Persist with

```
EnableViewState = true;
```

In order to don't erase your selected value

Answer (score 0):

If this is a silverlight application then you might want to use 
    cbLocStation.SelectedItem
Or it is a ASP.Net site and you rebind the data on every pageLoad

Either way you should have an exception because you are trying to convert a null value.

Answer (score 0):

See the method that you have used to bind the combo box

```
cbLocStation.Items.Add(locstationData);
```

This will create the combobox with "ValueField" and "TextFiled" with value of the variable "locstationData" 
So when you try to get selected value from `cbLocStation.SelectedValue` ,it will always contain name and so you cannot parse it to integer.

There is another overload for the "Add" Which will accept Value(Id) and Text(Text to display)

```
 cbLocStation.Items.Add(new ListItem(locstationData.locStatname, locstationData.locStatID));
```

Try to change the binding portion like this